# nodeJS dockerfile build failing with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile, npm-install

I am trying to create a docker container for NODEJS and get it to run a nodejs application.

It is failing on the npm install step with

```
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is the dockerfile

```
FROM node:onbuild

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN sudo npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and this is the package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "ioredis": "^1.15.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.5"
  }
}
```

and this is the build command I am running

```
 docker build -t jachno/nodejs .
```

it runs for ages pull loads of stuff in and then fails with an exit code of 1.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As an update, i was building this application in aws on an tiny free instance. basically this was cause by the box running out of memory during the build processes.

once I added more memory the build completed correctly

Comment: How did you add more memory?

Comment: Increase the instance size, can't remember what too, but you only need to increase it for the build duration. You can shrink it afterwards to save costs

Answer (score 0):

`FROM node:onbuild` this image has already installed npm package, right ? if not, install npm first.

For this:

```
# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN sudo npm install
```

Should be:

```
# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN cd /usr/src/app && npm install
```

Comment: try to install nodejs first : `RUN apt-get install -y nodejs` in dockerfile

Comment: or use base image: `FROM        ubuntu`

Comment: you can follow this : http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/